# SPFX with Angular 4 - should I use this approach?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, angular2

I'm just a new guy in the SPO.

Angular 4 + SPO - do you think that is Ok?

What kind of problem should I think first? Routes? trusted scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you few reasons to go with React js rather, more details [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-react-js-recommended-framework-developing-client-side-khan)

Answer (score 0):

It's a perfectly valid approach. I've used Angular with SharePoint before (but not SPFX) and it works fine. The Yeoman scaffolding doesn't provide an option for Angular though so you'll need to select "No Framework" and set it up yourself.